# In initial value second order DE problem, should the 2 conditions be at the same $x_0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's say that I have DE of $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$. To pick a particular solution, should the two conditions be [$y(x_0)=k_1$ and $y'(x_0)=k_2$]? or can be any other combinations of:

[$y(x_0)=k_1$ and $y'(x_0)=k_2$]

[$y(x_0)=k_1$ and $y'(x_1)=k_2$]

[$y(x_0)=k_1$ and $y(x_1)=k_2$]

[$y'(x_0)=k_1$ and $y'(x_1)=k_2$]

?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You might want to read about the [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm–Liouville_theory), in particular the notion of a *regular* SL problem.

Comment: The first case is the "simple" situation of an IVP. The latter three cases are *boundary* value problems, which are a significantly more subtle subject than IVPs. In particular even the question of existence/uniqueness is much more delicate in the BVP context.